# CSS: Class within Class

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Created two custom classes with the aim of achieving the below result:[image: Picture]

My CSS:

```
.custom_ccy_pricing {
    font-size:20px;
    top:-35px;
    position:relative;
    color:grey;
}

.custom_pricing {
    font-size:80px;
    font-family: ‘Raleway’;
    float:right;
    color: #7ebec5;
    font-weight:300;
}
```

My html:

```
 <div class="custom_ccy_pricing">$
     <div class="custom_pricing">50</div>
 </div>
```

No matter what, I can't seem to achieve the above - wordpress automatically assigns `<p>` to the text, as seen below (and what I end up with):

[image: inspect]

Result:

[image: result]

Thanks!

Comment: If there's no way of getting rid of that p tag then you could do: `.custom_ccy_pricing p { display: none; }`

Comment: This is questionable use of a `<div>`; how about a `<span>` instead, like `<div class="custom_ccy_pricing">$<span class="custom_pricing">50</span></div>`, all on one line?

Comment: `div` is a block element, so the `p` is inserted automatically (I think), you should set the `display:inline-block` for the `div` or use `span` as suggested by *yitwail*

Comment: thanks guys, I used span in the div and created a container around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<span>` instead of `<div>` for the text.

HTML:

```
<div class="pricing_holder">
<span class="custom_ccy_pricing">$
<span class="custom_pricing">50</span>
</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom_ccy_pricing {
font-size:20px;
*top:-35px;
position:relative;
color:grey;
width: 100px;
}

.custom_pricing {
font-size:80px;
font-family: ‘Raleway’;
float:right;
color: #7ebec5;
font-weight:300;
}
.pricing_holder {
width: 100px;
}
```

I am not sure if it works on wordpress, though.

Comment: thanks guys! I figured it out - used the above suggestion with a pricing_holder and the span's instead of divs.

Answer (score 1):

Make this:

```
<div class="custom_ccy_pricing">$
     <div class="custom_pricing">50</div>
</div>
```

This:

```
<div class="custom_ccy_pricing">$
     <span class="custom_pricing">50</span>
</div>
```

The `span` tag is specifically for styling text. Each time you make a new `div`, it makes a linebreak for you, as it is a block element.

`span` is an inline element, so there is no such linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the pesky p tags simply by writing the HTML on a single line like so...

```
<div class="custom_ccy_pricing">$<div class="custom_pricing">50</div></div>
```

The p tags are not your only problem, however!  You also need to keep the number (div.custom_pricing) together with the dollar sign (div.custom_ccy_pricing).  You already have some answers that suggest using a span for div.custom_pricing, but that won't work for you if you really need to float it.  The only reason for using a span is to enforce **display: inline** behavior, which is incompatible with floating.

I suggest something altogether different: add the dollar sign as a **::before** pseudo-element.  Here's how I would do it:

HTML

```
<div class="custom_pricing">50</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom_pricing::before {
color: gray;
content: "$";
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
position: absolute;
top: -35px; left:0;
}

.custom_pricing {
font-size:80px;
font-family: ‘Raleway’;
float:right;
color: #7ebec5;
font-weight:300;
}
```

You might want to learn more about the awesomeness of pseudo-elements here: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/